# Silverlight Tooltip Remain Visible With Mouseover

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, tooltip, silverlight-5.0

Hello and thanks for the help. I have a Treeview that I am populating with a Hierarchical data template, and currently the bottom nodes have a tooltip that generates a small stack panel that is populated with data specific to the item the mouse hovers over. I also have a button sitting in the tooltip, however, as the tooltip does not persist when the mouse moves over it, I am unable to make use of the button like I need to. My xaml looks like this:

```
<!--===========================  Hierarchical Data template  for tree view -->
                        <!--template for bottom nodes-->
                        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ModTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationModules}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                            <!--======tooltip style to handle format for callout window============-->
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip  HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0" Style="{StaticResource ModuleToolTipStyle}">

                                        <StackPanel Width="150" Height="auto" >
                             <TextBlock Text="Module Info" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Module State:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModInfo.ModuleState}" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="Module Start Time:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModInfo.ModuleStartTime}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Module Down Time:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModInfo.ModuleDownTime}" />
                                            <Button Content="More Info" Width="75"></Button>
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
               <!--============end tooltip style for callout window===================-->

                                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="{Binding Icon}" />
                                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=ModuleName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I would like the tooltip to persist when the mouse moves over it so that I can wire an event to the button. How can I achieve this? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: For my own edification, what do you mean by "persist" when the mouse moves over it? It's sounding like you just need a ToolTip.Template instead of just setting the Content. :/

Comment: I just need it to remain visible as the mouse pointer moves from the treeView item into the tooltip box itself, so that interaction, with a button in this case, is possible. Can you affect that through the ToolTip Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options to accomplish your goal that I'm aware of. You can go check out the [Silverlight Advanced Tooltips](http://tooltipservice.codeplex.com/) project over on codeplex which does what you want (though I personally have not used it so can't give any kind of review.)

Or you can make your own with some creativity. If it were me I would probably skip all that mess, forget the ToolTipService all together and just make my own to dress it up since to a user, what you're providing isn't what they're used to in terms of a tooltip expectation anyway and have cross more over to a callout or popout functionality. I can make an example as soon as I get some freed up time if option #1 doesn't work for you but I hope it does. Essentially both my way, and that project link I provided would do the same thing, which is provide a delay after the MouseLeave event of what it's attached to so the user can get to it before it disappears. Then hand off its visibility condition to that object. Let me know if this doesnt work and I can give you an alternative example using nothing but XAML.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the help. I will try your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: Good deal, if you run into issues let me know and we'll just whip something up. I'll be away all weekend though in case you dont get your solution before end of day and I dont respond but hopefully that does the trick for you. Cheers.